# Difficulties with VirtualScreenWidth and VirtualScreenHeight. Error message: Identifier expected

Tags: c#, windows-8, xna, monogame

At the beginning, I got this error message:
The type or namespace name 'VirtualScreenWidth' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
After that, I added "using System.Windows" and the error message disappeared.
But now, I always get this error message in the following two lines:

```
public static const VirtualScreenWidth = 800;
public static const VirtualScreenHeight = 480;
```

Identifier expected

What is wrong? What should I change? I found the code in this little tutorial:
http://www.craftworkgames.com/blog/monogame-resolution-independence/

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. I literally wrote that little tutorial just yesterday and typed out those lines and forgot to check them. I've updated the tutorial. I hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to define the type, e.g. integer:

```
public const int VirtualScreenWidth = 800;
```